# CFO estimation and compensation

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm

I am reading about CFO estimation in OFDM system, assume for example that we estimate it based on CP as mentioned [HERE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14079/carrier-frequency-offset-cfo-estimation-based-on-symbols) and the estimated CFO for the received signal $r(t)$ is $β$. My question, how now can we compensate that CFO on the time-domain signal $r(t)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any signal: multiply with an appropriate $e^{-j2\pi \beta n}$.

(That, by the way, directly results from the last line of the answer you've linked to.)